# add error description in loopback explorer

Tags: error-handling, loopback

By default, there's just a **success description** in **loopback explorer**
so, I want also to add **error description** like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just set `NODE_ENV` to development when starting node. You can see the errors and stack-trace.

`NODE_ENV="development" npm start`